# Can not add AspNetRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

Code for adding Role is:

```
var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore(ApplicationDbContext.Create()));
roleManager.Create(new Role("Admin"));
```

Error that I'm getting is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'DB_.dbo.AspNetRoles'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Here is my custom Identity models:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim> {
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager) {

        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, int,
    UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim> {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection") {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("AspNetRoles").HasKey(u => u.Id).Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); ;
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

// New derived classes
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> {

}

public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> {
}

public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> {
}

public class Role : IdentityRole<int, UserRole> {
    public Role() { }
    public Role(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class UserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, Role, int,
    UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim> {
    public UserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) {
    }
}

public class RoleStore : RoleStore<Role, int, UserRole> {
    public RoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) {
    }
}
```

I tried to add this line to force column to be identity, but with no luck:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("AspNetRoles").HasKey(u => u.Id).Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Tried also with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` with no luck.

`Claims`, `Users` and everything else works great. With this models I changed **Id** to be `int` not `string`.

Here it is RoleManager:

```
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, int> {
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager) {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user) {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context) {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}

public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<Models.Role, int> {
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<Models.Role, int> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore) {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context) {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new Models.RoleStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

AspNetRoles Table definition:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the table definition of your `AspNetRoles` table?

Comment: @pfx Here you go (Edited question). Table was generated from code. All other tables work great(claims, logins, users...)

Comment: Make sure that the `Id` column is defined as auto-increment identity; `Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)`.

Comment: You did change these from `String (VARCHAR)` to `Int`?

Comment: I changed Identity models, and all those tables are autocreated. I didn't touch anything in SQL Studio. I can't change now, because it has foreign key I think in AspNetUserRoles. I can only delete all tables and create them again with Identity and set foreign keys?

Comment: Anywhere you changed the datatype of the `Id` field in your code like the `int` in
`class Role : IdentityRole<int, UserRole>` you must also change the datatype of the corresponding column of the matching table in the database. If there is a foreign key relation, you also have to change it in similar way. `

Comment: I delete AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles in SQL, added those table agains with int primary and foreign key. And it works now. I don't know why Entity didn't made those tables with int-s like it did with AspNetUsers and Claims... Thank you @pfx for tips. ;)